# WITH clause in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a query

```
With Price as
(
      select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C,D from AB_TABLE
      WHERE TYPE = 'FULL'
)
```

I need to able to join this with another query

```
With New_Price as
(
      select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C from AB_TABLE
      WHERE TYPE = 'HALF'
)
```

How could I achieve this? I need this query for creating a view, so cant use SELECT with the WITH clause.
My apologies if this is confusing. But the query inside Price and New_Price is actually complicated and I want to join both of them to show records from both of them, probably by applying a UNION. Can someone please help here.

Comment: What do you mean you *"can't use `SELECT` with the `WITH` clause"*? A `WITH` is an expression (like a `CASE`, `IIF`, `CONVERT`, etc), there has to be a `SELECT` after all your CTEs have be declared..

Comment: You *can* use CTE's in a view creation.

Answer (score 1):

`WITH` handles multiple CTEs`:

```
With Price as (
      select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C,D
      from AB_TABLE
      WHERE TYPE = 'FULL'
    ),
    New_Price as (
     select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C
     from AB_TABLE
     WHERE TYPE = 'HALF'
   )
select . . .
from . . .
```

Comment: Thanks. But will it do a kind of UNION on the data? also, i cant use WITH i think, because this query is for view.

Comment: you can UNION or JOIN the table, and other options, it depends what output you want.

Comment: @Newbie . . . You can create views using CTEs.  You can use `UNION`.  The CTE can go anywhere a table can go in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for .

```
;With Price as (
      select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C,D
      from AB_TABLE
      WHERE TYPE = 'FULL'
    ),
    New_Price as (
     select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C
     from AB_TABLE
     WHERE TYPE = 'HALF'
   )

select ID, A,B,C from Price
 union ALL
select ID, A,B,C from New_Price
```

or

```
select DISTINCT ID, A,B,C,D
      from AB_TABLE
      WHERE TYPE = 'FULL' or TYPE = 'HALF'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Server `VIEW` can use multiple  `CTE`.

You can follow this

```
CREATE VIEW
AS
WITH
   CTE1 AS (SELECT * FROM T),
   CTE2 AS (SELECT * FROM T),
   CTE3 AS (SELECT * FROM T)
SELECT * CTE
```

Here is a [simple](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=46647b8e58bd3a5f572bb77b560d39f7)

```
CREATE VIEW test 
AS 
  WITH price 
       AS (SELECT DISTINCT id, 
                           a, 
                           b, 
                           c, 
                           d 
           FROM   ab_table 
           WHERE  type = 'FULL'), 
       new_price 
       AS (SELECT DISTINCT id, 
                           a, 
                           b, 
                           c 
           FROM   ab_table 
           WHERE  type = 'HALF') 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   (SELECT *
          FROM   price 
          UNION 
          SELECT *
          FROM   new_price) t
```